# Showing that the diagonal functor $\Delta:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ having a right adjoint implies $\mathbb{C}$ having products.

Tags: category-theory, products, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

I started brushing up on my understanding of adjunctions and came across this well-known fact (rephrased in my own words):

> Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a category, and let $\Delta:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$ be the functor mapping objects $C$ of $\mathbb{C}$ to objects $(C, C)$ in $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$.
>
> $\mathbb{C}$ has binary products if and only if $\Delta$ has a right adjoint.

The case where $\mathbb{C} = \mathsf{Set}$ is discussed in the introduction to *Categories for the Working Mathematician* and makes sense to me.
The more general fact is proven in Awodey's *Category Theory* and also mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Universal_property) and other [Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1518873/limit-functor-is-right-adjoint-to-diagonal-functor) questions.

However, I'm missing something to fully understand the available proof(s). I can see how $\mathbb{C}$ having products implies the existence of a right adjoint (namely the product functor). I do not understand though how the existence of a right adjoint implies that $\mathbb{C}$ has binary products.

To rule out any conceptual misunderstandings, let me clarify what I think it is that needs to be shown:

> For all $X, Y \in \mathrm{obj}(\mathbb{C})$ there exists an object $X \times Y \in \mathrm{obj}(\mathbb{C})$ together with morphisms $X \times Y \xrightarrow{\pi_1} X$ and $X \times Y \xrightarrow{\pi_2} Y$ such that for all $C \in \mathrm{obj}(\mathbb{C})$ and any two morphisms $C \xrightarrow{f} X$ and $C \xrightarrow{g} Y$ there exists a unique morphism $C \xrightarrow{\langle f, g \rangle} X \times Y$ such that $f = \pi_1 \circ \langle f, g \rangle$ and $g = \pi_2 \circ \langle f, g \rangle$.

This is how I would start:

Suppose there exists $R : \mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $\Delta \dashv R$. Then for all $C \in \mathrm{obj}(\mathbb{C})$ and all $(X, Y) \in \mathrm{obj}(\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C})$, we have that $\mathrm{hom}(\Delta(C), (X, Y)) \cong \mathrm{hom}(C, R(X, Y))$.

It follows that we can associate each morphism $(C, C) \xrightarrow{(f, g)} (X, Y)$ (i.e. each pair of morphisms $C \xrightarrow{f} X$ and $C \xrightarrow{g} Y$) with a unique morphism $C \xrightarrow{\langle f, g \rangle} R(X,Y)$.

This is where I get stuck (and where all other proofs that I've found end).

How do we know that there exist morphisms $R(X, Y) \xrightarrow{\pi_1} X$ and $R(X, Y) \xrightarrow{\pi_2} Y$ such that $f = \pi_1 \circ \langle f, g \rangle$ and $g = \pi_2 \circ \langle f, g \rangle$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to think about is, have you used all of the things which you assumed? One of the requirements of an adjunction, is that maps
$$
\alpha_{c,(x,y)}\colon \mathrm{Hom}(\Delta c, (x,y))\xrightarrow{\cong} \mathrm{Hom}(c, R(x,y))
$$
assemble into a *natural* isomorphism.
For an object $c$ with maps $f\colon c\to x, g\colon c \to y$, we get a unique map $\langle f, g\rangle \colon c\to R(x,y)$ by the adjunction.
Using this morphism, we obtain the following commutative sqaure:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathrm{Hom}(\Delta R(x,y), (x,y)) @>{\cong}>> \mathrm{Hom}(R(x,y), R(x,y))\\
  @V{(\Delta\langle f,g\rangle)^*}VV @V{\langle f,g\rangle^*}VV \\
\mathrm{Hom}(\Delta c, (x,y)) @>{\cong}>> \mathrm{Hom}(c, R(x,y))
\end{CD}
$$
Starting with $\mathrm{id}_{R(x,y)}$ on the top right, the following elements correspond:
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
(\pi_1,\pi_2)@>{\alpha}>> \mathrm{id}_{R(x,y)}\\
  @V{(\Delta\langle f,g\rangle)^*}VV @V{\langle f,g\rangle^*}VV \\
(f,g) @>{\alpha}>>\langle f, g \rangle
\end{CD}
$$
where $\pi_1,\pi_2$ are the names of the maps from $R(x,y)$ to $x$ and $y$ respectively, which show up under the horizontal bijection.
The $\pi_i$'s are actually independent of $c$, which is what we want.
The fact that $\Delta(\langle f,g\rangle)^*(\pi_1,\pi_2)= (f,g)$ precisely means that $\pi_1\circ \langle f,g\rangle = f$ and $\pi_2\circ \langle f,g\rangle = g$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! The diagrams are very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In the adjoint isomorphism
$$\operatorname{Hom}(C, R(X,Y))\cong \operatorname{Hom}(\Delta(C),(X,Y))$$
setting $C = R(X,Y)$ results to
$$\operatorname{Hom}(R(X,Y),R(X,Y)) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(\Delta(C),(X,Y)) \overset{def}{=} \operatorname{Hom}(R(X,Y),X)\times \operatorname{Hom}(R(X,Y),Y).$$
The morphisms $\pi_1:R(X,Y)\rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2:R(X,Y)\rightarrow Y$ are obtained by the image of the identity $\mathrm{id}_{R(X,Y)}$.